# Redirect to last page visited on 404 error

Tags: redirection

Just wondering if there is a simple way to automatically redirect users to the last page they have visited if they receive a 404 error? I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Wouldn't that be awfully confusing for your users?

Comment: it was a lazy work around for a view I had. Ended up doing something entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

There's a module for that: [CustomError](http://drupal.org/project/customerror), which has a development snapshot for Drupal 7.

> This module allows the site admin to create custom error pages for 404 (not found), and 403 (access denied), without the need to create nodes for each of them.
>
> Since the error pages are not real nodes, they do not belong a category term, they do not show in the search, and will not show up in node listings, or in Popular Content block.

Comment: I believe there hasn't been a release of this module for D7

Comment: There is a development snapshot for Drupal 7 that is currently available from the project page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom module:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_boot() {
  if(!menu_get_item($_GET['q'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']) {
      header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `menu_get_item()` is only available when Drupal completes its bootstrap, while `hook_boot()` implementations are invoked in the second bootstrap phase.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting users automatically, I suggest you provide a link in the 404 page to link back to the previous page. You can make use of `HTTP_REFERRER` to link back, or any other approach.